# Databinding fails with NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

After updating to gradle 2.10 every time when I try to `assemble` debug build of the app I get the `NoSuchMethodError` exception. Here is the relevant part of the build log:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: failure, see logs for details.
  cannot generate view binders java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Strings.isNullOrEmpty(Ljava/lang/String;)Z
    at android.databinding.tool.util.StringUtils.capitalize(StringUtils.java:57)
    at android.databinding.tool.util.ParserHelper.toClassName(ParserHelper.java:23)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.ResourceBundle$LayoutFileBundle.getFullBindingClass(ResourceBundle.java:551)
    at android.databinding.tool.store.ResourceBundle$LayoutFileBundle.getBindingClassPackage(ResourceBundle.java:541)
    at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.pushClassesToAnalyzer(CompilerChef.java:124)
    at android.databinding.tool.CompilerChef.createChef(CompilerChef.java:73)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.writeResourceBundle(ProcessExpressions.java:148)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessExpressions.onHandleStep(ProcessExpressions.java:82)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.runStep(ProcessDataBinding.java:154)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding$ProcessingStep.access$000(ProcessDataBinding.java:139)
    at android.databinding.annotationprocessor.ProcessDataBinding.process(ProcessDataBinding.java:66)
```

As you can see Method `com.google.common.base.Strings.isNullOrEmpty` can't be found.

**Some specifics**

I use Retrolambda `3.2.5` and Java 8. There are no other extra plugins.

Build plugin version: `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0`

Build tools version: `23.0.3`

OS: `OS X`

`build.gradle` looks like this. I altered it slightly to not expose some private stuff, but problem is still there.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

project.version = '1.0.0'

afterEvaluate {
    tasks.matching {
        it.name.startsWith('dex')
    }.each { dx ->
        if (dx.additionalParameters == null) {
            dx.additionalParameters = []
        }
        dx.additionalParameters += "--set-max-idx-number=50000" //    default 60000
    }
}

def googleApiKey = "key goes here"
def appVersionCode = 1
def appVersionName = project.version + "." + appVersionCode

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        manifestPlaceholders = [googleApiKey  : googleApiKey,
                                appVersionCode: appVersionCode,
                                appVersionName: appVersionName]
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.cfg'

            applicationVariants.all { variant ->
                variant.outputs.each { output ->
                    output.outputFile = new File(
                            output.outputFile.parent,
                            "App-${project.version}-${appVersionCode}.apk"
                    )
                }
            }
        }

        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions "multidex", "leakcanary"

    productFlavors {
        withLeakCanary {
            dimension "leakcanary"
        }

        withoutLeakCanary {
            dimension "leakcanary"
        }

        develDex {
            dimension "multidex"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 23
        }

        prodDex {
            dimension "multidex"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 23
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'build/jniLibs'
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

task copyNativeLibs(type: Copy) {
    from(new File(buildDir, 'intermediates/exploded-aar/')) {
        include '**/*.so'
        exclude '**/lib-detector.so'
    }
    into new File(buildDir, 'jniLibs')
    eachFile { details ->
        def pathSplit = details.path.split('/')
        details.path = pathSplit[pathSplit.length - 2] + '/' +    pathSplit[pathSplit.length - 1]
    }

    includeEmptyDirs = false
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { javaCompileTask ->    javaCompileTask.dependsOn copyNativeLibs }

clean.dependsOn 'cleanCopyNativeLibs'

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:shadows-multidex:3.0'
    testCompile('org.robolectric:shadows-httpclient:3.0') {
        exclude module: 'httpcore'
        exclude module: 'commons-codec'
    }
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.5.2'
    testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.5.2'
    testCompile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1'

    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.0.1'
    provided 'org.roboguice:roboblender:3.0.1'
    compile('com.google.inject.extensions:guice-assistedinject:3.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.inject', module: 'guice'
    }
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile 'com.intellij:annotations:12.0'

    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.zxing:android-core:3.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.amazon:in-app-purchasing:2.0.1'

    compile 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:7.0.7'

    withLeakCanaryCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.8.0'

    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
}
```

**Question**

Did anyone else had the same problem? How to fix it? If you need some extra information, please let me know in comments.

Comment: Can you post your full `build.gradle` once ? I think It has nothing to do with `Retrolambda`.

Comment: Thanks for the response see [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.google.guava/guava/11.0.2/com/google/common/base/Strings.java#Strings.isNullOrEmpty%28java.lang.String%29)  `isNullOrEmpty()` method belongs to `com.google.guava`, and frequently checked in [gradle](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=isNullOrEmpty&type=Code) And I didn't see that in your gradle. I'm also confused because I was not encountered that issue even I made same specification as yours.

Comment: What happens if you add dependency of guava at first
By compiling group  `compile group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '18.0'` in dependency ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna I already tried to add Guava as `classpatch` dependency. Just tried to add it as a `compile` - it still produces the same error. As for being able to reproduce the problem - I have another OS X machine, I tried to reproduce the problem there but everything just worked fine. So, I suspected that build tools are the reason and completely reinstalled them (even deleted `.gradle` folder), but error still remains.

Comment: Bro, You may have tried changing many things than I could imagine,  You may have probably changed gradle classpath to *2.1.0-rc1* as well. `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-rc1'`. But it's really a tough issue as you said in one Machine worked fine and in another didn't work. Good luck and hope you'll solve this issue soon..

Comment: Please don't laugh, but did you try to clean the build? Often this fixed my problems with the data binding API.

Comment: Also, ensure you are using the right version of Android Studio as com.google.common.base.Strings.isNullOrEmpty is part of AndroidFacetModuleCustomizer for Android idea's gradle.

Comment: @lodlock, I was actually building the app in Terminal. One of my machines don't have Android Studio installed. Another one has only AS 1.5

Comment: @rekire sorry for long response. Yes, I tried clean build. Both `clean` task as well as just wiping out `build` folders.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna thanks for suggestion, but unfortunately problem remains even with `2.1.0-rc1`.

Comment: It's taking an incorrect library. Did you check try the `-verbose:class` JVM option? It shows all classes that are loaded. You may want to compare that to the other machine.

Comment: @Roberg thanks for the suggestion, just tried that. Seems like the same version of Guava is used as well as same version of Databinding library

Comment: The JVM build level? Although I can hardly imagine..

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the new patch on jitpack of simular issue #134 clean-build, there seemed to be something wrong with gradle import ordering you can try it with :

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.github.denis-itskovich:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3-fix-134'
}
```

Comment: With that I got 2 build errors. One is still the same, the other one is coming from retrolambda: `Cannot get property 'allJava' on null object`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an error with a plugin after upgrading the Android Studio.

If you go in : `<Android Studio Dir>/plugins/android/lib/builder-model-x.x.x.jar` you may find 2 .jars. Try to delete the old version .jar and keep the new one and also clean and rebuild the project.

if the above does not work try this:

Change the version of Objectify library in the build.gradle file of your backend to 4.0b to 5.0.3 or higher if it exists.

This is may sound irrelevant but objectify 4.0b library has same classes with same package name which are present in appengine sdk like com.google.common.base.Strings.isNullOrEmpty.

when you deploy the app backend the appengine classes are overridden by objectify classes and hence when you try to call some method it is throwing error.

This is solved in objectify 5.0.+

Hope it helps as it helped me solving this issue.

Comment: There are no IDEs installed on the machine. Objectify is not used either (gradle project contains only the app client).